# Update jsonb type column based on data from another table

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table **orders** with jsonb field **eventlog** and I have another table **ids_tmp** with two columns **old_id and new_id**.
The jsonb **eventlog** field has attributes **userId** with values equal to **old_id** from **ids_tmp** within json array.

I have to change old_id'es to new_id'es in **eventlog**.
I have this script, but i dont understand how to put result json to specific row in **orders**

```
UPDATE  orders g
SET     eventlog = s.json_array
FROM (
    SELECT 
        jsonb_agg(
             CASE WHEN exists (select 1 from ids_tmp h where cast(h.old_id as varchar) = elems ->> 'userId') THEN
                 jsonb_set(elems, '{userId}', ( select cast(cast(h.new_id as varchar) as jsonb) from ids_tmp h where cast(h.old_id as varchar) = elems ->> 'userId' ))
             ELSE elems  END
        ) as json_array
    FROM
        orders,
        jsonb_array_elements(eventlog) elems
) s
```

Comment: You either need to join the `orders` rows from the `FROM` clause to the `orders g` that you're updating (by order id or something, in a `WHERE` statement), or you should use a subquery in the `SET` clause instead of using a `FROM`.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

```
update orders o 
set eventlog = ( 
    SELECT 
        jsonb_agg(
             CASE WHEN exists (select 1 from ids_tmp h where cast(h.old_idas varchar) = elems ->> 'userId') THEN
                 jsonb_set(elems, '{userId}', ( select cast(cast(h.new_id as varchar) as jsonb) from ids_tmp  h where cast(h.old_id as varchar) = elems ->> 'userId' ))
             ELSE elems  END
        ) as json_array
    FROM
        jsonb_array_elements(o.eventlog) elems  
)
where o.id in (
        select  d.id
        from    orders d, 
                jsonb_array_elements(eventlog) elems
        where   exists (select 1 from ids_tmp h where cast(h.old_id as varchar) = elems ->> 'userId')
    )
;
```

Comment: The outer `where` clause seems superfluous. And the inner `where` clause can be dropped if you just refer to `o` instead of `tt` everywhere

Comment: thanks for the tip. About outer `where` clause, I wanted to limit the amount of affected data in order table

Comment: Besides, in my case without outer `where` clause, the update takes much longer

Answer (score 0):

You either need to join the `orders` rows from the `FROM` clause to the `orders g` that you're updating (by order id or something, in a `WHERE` statement):

```
UPDATE  orders g
SET     eventlog = s.json_array
FROM (
    SELECT
        o.id,
        jsonb_agg(
             CASE WHEN h.new_id IS NOT NULL
             THEN jsonb_set(elems, '{userId}', h.new_id)
             ELSE elems END
        ) as json_array
    FROM
        orders o,
        LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(o.eventlog) elems,
        LEFT JOIN ids_temp h ON h.old_id = (elems ->> 'userId')::int
    GROUP BY
        o.id
--  ^^^^^^^^ also necessary
) s
WHERE   g.id = s.id;
--      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or you should use a subquery referencing `g` in the `SET` clause instead of using a `FROM`:

```
UPDATE  orders g
SET     eventlog = (
    SELECT 
        jsonb_agg(
             CASE WHEN h.new_id IS NOT NULL
             THEN jsonb_set(elems, '{userId}', h.new_id)
             ELSE elems END
        )
    FROM
        jsonb_array_elements(g.eventlog) elems,
--                           ^
        LEFT JOIN ids_temp h ON h.old_id = (elems ->> 'userId')::int
)
```

Also I've taken the liberty to simplify that `WHEN EXISTS(…)` subquery into a left join.